# Can you create a windows scheduled task to run every day except sunday?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Should be very easy  but the answer evades me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried a "Weekly" trigger with all but "Sunday" checked?

Comment: I've not tested that, by the way!

Comment: It seems logical. I will be running it this week and will report back.

Comment: Please do - I'm genuinely interested

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dan I've tested this and it works... every day of every week, except Sunday.